# Use of unassigned local variable in nopcommerce 3.0 source

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, e-commerce, nopcommerce

I want to parse an attributes value and add it to the PDF that `nopCommerce` generates,

I currently have in the Pdfservice.cs:

```
//DOCID        

string documentId;

int attributeId;

var item = orderProductVariant;

var document = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(item.AttributesXml);

var attribute = document.Element("Attributes").Elements("ProductVariantAttribute").Where(e => e.Attribute("ID") != null && e.Attribute("ID").Value == attributeId.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();

if (attribute != null)
{
    var value = attribute.Descendants("Value").FirstOrDefault();

}

cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(documentId?? String.Empty, font));
cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
productsTable.AddCell(cell);
```

I'm now getting this error

```
use of unassigned local variable on documentId and attributeId
```

I copied this code from the `shoppingCartController`, where these variable are declared in this line:

```
private ShoppingCartItem FindItemFromDocumentId(string documentId,IEnumerable<ShoppingCartItem> cart,int attributeId)
```

My question now is how do I declare those variables in the edited Pdfservice.cs so that the `documentID` will parse.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving them a value first, before using them:

```
string documentId = "";  // or `null`, if that's appropriate in your case
int attributeId = 0;
```

You're trying to use these variables later in your code, but they have no value yet:

- `documentId ?? String.Empty`
- `attributeId.ToString()`

---

Actually, if the signature on your method is

```
private ShoppingCartItem FindItemFromDocumentId(string documentId,IEnumerable<ShoppingCartItem> cart,int attributeId)
```

Then just remove the following two lines and use the parameters you're already passing to the method:

```
string documentId;
int attributeId;
```